# trackbar not changing the video position in vlc player

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on project in which I have embed VideoLan vlc plugin 1.1.7. So there is no trackbar in it by default. I have added track bar manually but it did not changing the video position(increment/decrements). here is my code

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBar1.Value += 1;
        if (trackBar1.Value == trackBar1.Maximum)
        {
            trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Minimum;
            timer2.Stop();
            trackBar1.Value += 0;
        }
    }

    private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bar = (TrackBar)sender;
        if (bar.Value % bar.SmallChange != 0)
        {

            bar.Value = bar.SmallChange * ((bar.Value + bar.SmallChange / 2) / bar.SmallChange);
        }
    }
```

Now how to control(increment/decrements) the video position with the help of mouse?

Comment: also, check out `DirectShowLib`, and `AxWMPLib` aka `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`. if you want to roll your own from the ground up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the plugin is not well documented.

You can set the Position property of the plugin, e.g.

```
axVLC.Position += 0.005f;
```

Note that it is a float!

But for my version (v1) there **is** a trackbar (and all other controls) once I move the mouse towards the bottom of the viewpost.

I don't have v2 but I think you should use

```
axVLC.input.Position
```

here. Also I think (but don't know!) that the units used are different; it could be 1/100th of a second..

Comment: but I have no Idea about v1 version coding... As the code for v1 and v2 is same ?

Comment: Position keyword not defined in my code?(for vlc plugin v2)

Comment: @Hanif See the Edit! BTW: Where did you get v2 from? My the latest VLC on my W8.1 machine I only got me v1.

Comment: I have win 7. I am using vlc 1.1.7 . in which I have two plugin . VideoLan activex plugin v1 and v2.

Comment: axVLC.input.Position += 0.005f; work but, it go forward in any way. I mean when I click on track bar towards forward or backward it increase video in forward side. not in backward ? what going on wrong?

Comment: Of course this example goes only forward as `+=` is an addition! You have to __calculate__ the amount you want and then __add__ or __subtract__ it.. The calculation may be tricky and involve input.Length and some scaling, but I can't help you out with the scaling with my version. The usual way is to change the Value of the TrackBar and then assign it (with scaling) to input.Position. Note: I found Length to work only after the playback has started, so I could assign the proper Maximum value only then..